# SQL - Return values that meet all criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Table1
site | value
a | banana
b | banana
c | banana
a | fred
c | quetzal
a | quetzal
```

Let's say I have a set of rows with site values

```
a
b
c
```

How do I find what values in Table1 have all three of a,b, and c for site?

I know that

```
SELECT value
FROM Table1
WHERE site IN (SELECT site FROM chosen_sites)
```

Will return all values that exist for at least one of the chosen sites, but how do I select the ones in all three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I think something like this:

```
select t.value
from Table1 t
join chosen_sites s on s.site = t.site
group by t.value
having count(distinct t.site) = (select count(*) from chosen_sites)
```

Edit: [seems to work](http://rextester.com/live/SKIW2563).

Answer (score 1):

You can `cross join` all distinct values with sites and `left join` table1 on to this and check for counts.

```
select v.value
from table2 t2 --this is your table2 with all sites
cross join (select distinct value from table1) v
left join table1 t1 on t1.site=t2.site and t1.value=v.value
group by v.value
having count(t2.site)=count(t1.site)
```